# Batch file to delete first 3 lines of a excel file

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

In need of a batch script to remove first 3 lines of an excel sheet...searched enough but got only few links that will work on csv and text files.
tried the below code too

```
@echo off
set "file=MAR2016.xlsx"
set "fnew=copyMAR2016.xlsx"
more +3 "%file%" >"%fnew%"
move /y "%fnew%" "%file%" >nul
```

Any help??

Comment: An xlsx is a binary file, not a text based file, so it would be incredibly tricky to remove the first three rows from it, without using another utility to do so. There are Java libraries or C# libraries available to let you do this with ease, but you'll need to code it accordingly to do your specific requirement here.

Comment: VBScript can handle Excel files _far_ more easily than batch can. If you absolutely _must_ use batch, you have to use a third-party archival software like WinRAR or 7-zip to unarchive the .xlsx file, then edit the appropriate file in the resulting folder, then _rearchive_ everything back into an .xlsx file. More trouble than it's worth, IMO. Just use VBScript.

Comment: public void Main(){   string FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::VarFilePath"].Value.ToString();
            Int32 DeleteTopNRows = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["VarDeleteTopNRows"].Value);
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
            lines = lines.Skip(DeleteTopNRows).ToArray();
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(FilePath);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {file.WriteLine(line);}
            file.Close();
  } I could manage to get the above C# coding to remove lines from csv not excel.Any help with excel .